# JavaScript Get SharePoint Online List from App

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web, add-in, sharepoint-online

I have my SharePoint Online list on Site Collection level

```
mydomain/sites/dev/Lists/MyList
```

I am developing a custom SharePoint-hosted app which is on

```
mydomain/sites/dev/MyApp
```

I currently have this bit of javascript code:

```
var siteUrl = 'mydomain/sites/dev';
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
```

And I get an error:

```
Request failed. List 'MyList' does not exist at site with URL 
mydomain/sites/dev/MyApp
```

So I need to reach the parent/root web somehow...

I've tried adding `.get_rootWeb()` like this

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
```

But then I get:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'get_rootWeb'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by replacing

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
```

with

```
var oList = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb().get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
```